# How to allow http delete endpoint in spring security version 6.x and spring boot 3.x

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using spring security version 6.1.2 and spring boot version 3.1.2. Below is my spring security configuration. Http method GET, POST, PUT is working fine but DELETE is not working with message 403 Forbidden. Do I need to add any special configuration to allow HTTP DELETE in spring security config.

**WebSecurityConfig:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity // 1
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests((authorizeRequests) -> authorizeRequests.requestMatchers("/**").hasAnyAuthority("USER"))
                .httpBasic(withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    WebSecurityCustomizer ignoringCustomizer() {
        return (web) ->          web.ignoring().requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET).requestMatchers("/user");
    }
}
```

**UserService code:**

```
@Service
public class UserServiceSecurity implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    UserRepoSecurity userRepo;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        final UserPojo user = userRepo.findByUserName(username);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
        }
        UserDetails userr = User.withUsername(user.getUserName()).password(user.getPassword()).authorities("USER")
                .build();
        return userr;
    }

}
```

**Controller:**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/products")
public class ProductController {
    @Autowired
    ProductService productService;

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ProductPojo getById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return productService.getByID(id);
    }

    @GetMapping
    public Iterable<ProductPojo> getAll() {
        return productService.getAll();
    }

    @PostMapping
    public ProductPojo createProduct(@RequestBody ProductPojo product) {
        return productService.createProduct(product);
    }

    @PutMapping
    public ProductPojo update(@RequestBody ProductPojo product) {
        return productService.update(product);

    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public String remove(@PathVariable Long id) {
        productService.remove(id);
        return "Record delete successfully";
    }
}
```

**Below is error on postman:**

[Error at postman when I hit HTTP DELETE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtjCt.png)

When I try to hit HTTP DELETE using postman, it gives 403 Forbidden.
URL for HTTP DELETE: http://localhost:8080/products/1

Comment: Any particular reason to why you havnt enable debug logs and read them before asking here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@EnableWebSecurity`  enables spring security and it by default enables csrf support.

And also `authorizeRequests` is deprecated use `authorizeHttpRequests` instead.
Also you should add `CORS` configuration that allow specific request.

The `securityFilterChain` body method should be something like this.

```
  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.cors(corsConfigurer -> corsConfigurer.configurationSource(corsConfiguration()))
        .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
    http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeRequests->
            authorizeRequests.requestMatchers("/**").hasAnyAuthority("USER"))
        .httpBasic(withDefaults());
    return http.build();
  }

  @Bean
  public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfiguration() {
    return request -> {
      org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration config = 
          new org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration();
      config.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
      config.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList("*"));
      config.setAllowedOriginPatterns(Collections.singletonList("*"));
      config.setAllowCredentials(true);
      return config;
    };
  }
```